# Groovy - formatting boolean expressions

Tags: groovy

I have just tried to write my first ever Groovy script and noticed that the following method does not work as I would expect it to (at first glance at least).

```
boolean isComment(String line)
{
    line = line.trim();
    return
        line.startsWith('//') ||
        line.startsWith('/*') ||
        line.startsWith('*') ||
        line.startsWith('*/');
}
```

I realized that (due to the fact that semicolons are optional in Groovy) the method body is in fact:

1. An assignment to the "line" variable.
2. An empty return statement (!), which evaluates to and returns false.
3. Four other (non-reachable) independent statements.

To me, the inability to format expressions in order to improve readability seems as quite a drawback.

What is the correct Groovy way to express such a method?

Comment: Is a line starting with a closing comment a comment line? Also, if you're not parsing groovy, a line could start with an asterisk.

Comment: (Actually, at least in some circumstances, if you're parsing Groovy, too.)

Comment: The code snippet comes from a simple script to count relevant lines of code (e.g. non-empty and non-comment lines) of my projects. However, my primary concern is in how to format Groovy code for readability without breaking the syntax rules. The code snippet should serve just as an example.

Comment: I don't understand why there's a `(!)` that a bare `return` would be evaluated as exactly what it is; it's syntactically valid. In any case, see my answer for a number of Groovier options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the logic not actually indicating what lines are comments, the easiest is this:

```
boolean isComment(String line) {
  line = line.trim()
  return line.startsWith('//') ||
         line.startsWith('/*') ||
         line.startsWith('*')  ||
         line.startsWith('*/')
}
```

IMO this is easier to comprehend quickly anyway.

Skipping the unnecessary return also eliminates the issue:

```
boolean isComment(String line) {
  line = line.trim()

  line.startsWith('//') ||
  line.startsWith('/*') ||
  line.startsWith('*')  ||
  line.startsWith('*/')
}
```

Another option would be to wrap the conditional in parens:

```
boolean isComment(String line) {
  line = line.trim()
  return (
    line.startsWith('//') ||
    line.startsWith('/*') ||
    line.startsWith('*')  ||
    line.startsWith('*/')
  )
}
```

Another option would be to use something closer to this:

```
def boolean isComment(String line) {
  line = line.trim()
  ['//', '/*', '*', '*/'].any { 
    line.startsWith(it)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
boolean isComment(String line) {
  line ==~ /^\s*(\/\/|\/\*|\*).*$/
}
```

Comment: Actually I wasn't wondering how to match comment lines in a better way. The question was about how to format boolean expressions for readability without breaking Groovy syntax. The included method code should serve just as an example. Should I edit the question to make this more apparent?